# Slow boot after adding new SSD (LUKS+LVM)

Tags: boot, 20.04, lvm, luks

**tl;dr:** After adding a new SSD to my current Ubuntu installation, the boot time has gone up from 8 to 70 seconds.

---

Hi,

my system is running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot setup. When I installed both systems, each OS had one SSD for itself and I also installed Ubuntu within a LVM layer, within a LUKS container. The output of `lsblk` looked like this:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    1 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    1     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                  8:2    1 930,5G  0 part  
  └─sda2_crypt        253:0    0 930,5G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-swap 253:1    0    40G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root 253:2    0    40G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-home 253:4    0 850,5G  0 lvm   /home
```

With this setup, the boot time between entering the disk encryption key and login prompt was ~8 seconds.

A few days ago, I added another SSD to my system. I encrypted the new disk with the same password as the old SSD, then I added the new SSD to the volume group of the old SSD and added the new space to the home LV. The output of `lsblk` now looks like this:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    1 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    1     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                  8:2    1 930,5G  0 part  
  └─sda2_crypt        253:0    0 930,5G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-swap 253:1    0    40G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root 253:2    0    40G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-home 253:4    0   1,6T  0 lvm   /home
sdb                     8:16   1 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                  8:17   1 931,5G  0 part  
  └─sdb1_crypt        253:3    0 931,5G  0 crypt 
    └─ubuntu--vg-home 253:4    0   1,6T  0 lvm   /home
```

I also added the new disk to the crypttab file:

```
sda2_crypt UUID=4ee8650c-bb07-4223-aab4-9b6327b9c641 none luks,discard
sdb1_crypt UUID=9c7a67f9-32fb-432d-a21f-5b42553911fc none luks,discard
```

The system is booting, but the boot time between entering the disk encryption key and login prompt has gone up to ~70 seconds. After entering the disk encryption key, two warning messages are printed and the system is hanging there for ~60 seconds:

```
WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid T8h7bF-ZJGn-rHTL-o0A5-fKtU-b1E9-dqV2TB.
WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV T8h7bF-ZJGn-rHTL-o0A5-fKtU-b1E9-dqV2TB (last written to /dev/mapper/sdb1_crypt).
```

The mentioned UUID references the LVM layer on the new SSD (sdb1_crypt).

I tried to find out, who is at fault for the longer boot time, but to no avail. I concluded that GRUB shouldn't be the problem here, because it is able to start the kernel and doesn't do any LUKS/LVM specific tasks. Systemd is responsible for caching the encryption key, but the logs show only a 2 second difference between the decryption of both disks:

```
Jun 08 16:46:47 nyx lvm[1157]:   pvscan[1157] PV /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt online, VG ubuntu-vg incomplete (need 1).
...
Jun 08 16:46:49 nyx lvm[1538]:   pvscan[1538] PV /dev/mapper/sdb1_crypt online, VG ubuntu-vg is complete.
```

`systemd-analyze` shows that most of the time is used by the kernel:

```
Startup finished in 26.113s (firmware) + 3.895s (loader) + 1min 25.304s (kernel) + 7.837s (userspace) = 2min 3.150s 
graphical.target reached after 7.830s in userspace
```

I have no glue what the kernel is waiting for, or in which direction to go from here. Maybe someone with a better understanding of the boot process can point me into the right direction?

Comment: In the output of `lsblk`, two partitions seem to be mounted to `/home`; could that cause problems?

Comment: I think this is the expected behavior. Because LVM contains both SSDs and the home partition uses parts of both disks. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, I found an answer to this topic after days of search in the link below.

> Solution
>
> I've solved the problem by adding the initramfs flag in /etc/crypttab
> and using keyscript=decrypt_keyctl instead of a keyfile to avoid
> entering the password two times for the second drive:
>
> luksSSD UUID=[UUID1]    none
> luks,initramfs,discard,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl luksHDD UUID=[UUID2]
> none    luks,initramfs,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
>
> Afterwards update-initramfs -c -k all needs to be executed and the
> problem is solved.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643344/linux-mint-20-with-luks-and-lvm-hangs-on-boot-after-upgrade

Comment: See [these](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5490/in-an-answer-should-i-link-to-the-same-question-found-on-unixlinux-stackexchan?rq=1) [answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16198/question-is-a-duplicate-of-a-question-on-another-stack-exchange-website) for how to respond with an answer from another StackExchange site, and welcome to AskUbuntu! In short, copy the answer as a quote and link back to that other page. The answers here should be relatively self-contained.